# AIR modules + iOS

Tags: ios, memory-management, air, module

We are building a large-scale app with AIR for iOS.

One constraint of an AIR app with the iOS packager is that there are no modules. It is possible to load SWF files, but any embedded actionscript code is ignored.

We are wondering what happens to an AIR app for iPad when the code size gets very large. Are you aware of any technique for dividing code up into logical load groups, or do app developers just rely on virtual memory to swap in only a subset (hopefully) of the entire binary image?

Answer (score 0):

**No, AIR does not allow package more than one primary SWF.**

We have a quite large project and wanted to use modules as well.

**Solution** we ended up with was **removing all embedded sources**. That includes graphics and sounds libraries created by Flash IDE or `[Embed]` classes.

All resources are loaded at runtime using

- [Sound](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/media/Sound.html).load() for mp3/sounds
- [Loader](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/display/Loader.html).load() with [asynchronous image decoding policy](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/as3/dev/WS52621785137562065a8e668112d98c8c4df-8000.html) for png/jpeg/images
- [FileStream](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/filesystem/FileStream.html).openAsync() for other/binary data.

We had 36 MB SWF file, now it is only 1.4 MB plus all the external assets.